# Bounded variation for $f$ piecewise monotone on countable set of disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble formally solving the following problem:

> Let $F$ be piecewise monotone on a countable sequence of disjoint
> intervals $\{[a_k, b_k]\}_{k=1}^\infty$.
>
> Prove that $F$ has bounded
> variation on $\cup_{k=1}^\infty[a_k,b_k]$ if and only if
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |F(b_k)-F(a_k)|$ converges.

For the "only if" part (assuming $T_a^b(F)<\infty$), I tried to show that any partition of this union of intervals (if I can even state that) that includes the first $N$ interval boundaries, would yield:

$$T_a^b(f) \geq \sum_1^N|f(a_i)-f(b_i)|$$

but this is not helpful, since the infinite sum is obviously larger that this.

For the "if" part, I tried using the supremum definition of total variation to bound it by the series as such:

There exists a partition $P=x_0<x_1<...<x_n$ of this union for which:
$$T_a^b(f) \leq \sum_1^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|+\epsilon$$

Since the series converges, there is an $N$ such that $\sum_N^\infty|f(a_i)-f(b_{i-1})| < \delta$.

Then I thought of using the first $N$ somehow to refine the partition $P$ in order to claim that $\sum_1^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| = \sum_1^N|f(a_i)-f(b_{i-1})|$ (this can be shown using a telescoping sum, since $f$ is piecewise monotone within each interval), so we obtain:

$$T_a^b(f) \leq \sum_1^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|+\epsilon \leq \sum_1^N|f(a_i)-f(b_i)|+\epsilon$$

which is finite since the series converges.
Is this correct? (the last inequality feels like it lacks some formality).

Any ideas how to solve this properly and formally?

Comment: Is $F$ required to be monotone on *each* of the intervals $[a_k,b_k]$?

Comment: From my understanding of the question that is the case.

Comment: My other question is what definition are we using?  Suppose $F(x)=k$ on each interval $[a_k,b_k]$.  Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |F_k(b_k)-F(a_k)|=0< \infty$.  But $F$ is not bounded on this set, but somehow it has bounded variation?

Comment: Why would this necessitate $F$ not being bounded?

Comment: If $F$ assumes every value $k=1,2,3,\dots$ on the set $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [a_i,b_i]$ then $F$ is unbounded on $S$.   I would expect any normal definition of bounded variation to imply bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Not much interest here and not much activity.

I would say that the problem is   meaningless as stated, either because it was transcribed wrongly or is missing some material that would clarify.

Instead here is how to pose this problem in an important and meaningful way.  There is a close connection between the concepts of bounded variation and monotonicity.  Jordan knew that piecewise monotonic functions [i.e., finite number of pieces] would have bounded variation.  He characterized the BV functions as equivalent to those that are linear combinations of monotone functions.

The spirit of the OP question is probably better given in this way:

**Q1.  Suppose that $\{b_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of real numbers for which $b_n\to a$ as $n\to \infty$.  Let $F:[a,b_1]\to \mathbb R$ with the property that $F$ is monotonic on each of the intervals $[b_{n+1},b_n]$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$.
Show that $F$ has bounded variation on $[a,b_1]$ if and only if**
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |F(b_n)-F(b_{n+1})|< \infty. \tag{1}$$

As a natural follow-up question, apply this problem to this situation.

**Q2. For any $p>0$ define the function $F:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by writing
$$  F(x) = x^p \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{x} \right) \tag{2}$$
for $0<x\leq 1$ with any value assigned for $x=0$.  State necessary and sufficient conditions so that $F$ has bounded variation on $[0,1]$.**

Further follow-up in the same spirit:

**Q3.  Just how many instances are there where the functions in (2) can be used for interesting examples and counterexamples in elementary real analysis?**

*Hint for Q3*: See this Monthly article:  Kaptanoğlu, H. Turgay,
In praise of $y=x^α \sin(\frac1x)$.
Amer. Math. Monthly 108 (2001), no. 2, 144–150.

---

*Need a picture for one of these functions?*
[image]